# how to write jsp struts2 for loop

Tags: jsp, for-loop, struts2

I want to write a for loop in jsp like this

```
for(int i = 0; i< max;i++){
  print("something");
}
```

where "max" and "something" are in variables in action class. what are the tags to write this. can you provide me sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use struts2 iterator tag

**[Documentation and Examples on Apache Struts2 Website](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/iterator.html)**

Also, I would suggest reading a **[Documentation/Get Started](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/home.html)** or **[Tutorial](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/tutorials.html)** before  getting started on a struts2-web project.